# ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_3 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 23)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(22, input_shape=(360,1)))
model.add(Dense(22, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
model.fit(X_res, y_res, epochs=2, batch_size=500)
```

I can not figure out what am I doing wrong. I am working on some one else's code where it is perfectly functioning.

Comment: What are the dimensions of X_res?

Comment: it is a pandas data frame

Comment: Then after importing the values from DataFrame, you can reshape the data to have shape 1 at its final axis.

Comment: What is the shape of your training dataset? It should match with the input_shape() you defined inside your sequential model.

Answer (score 1):

It is expecting 3 channels however 2 channels are given.

Here is the relevant [article](https://saturncloud.io/blog/keras-how-to-input-a-3channel-image-into-lstm-for-advanced-deep-learning/) for your reference for using LSTM in keras.

You can use this code to match the flavour of your application , though this is example is for for Image.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Flatten, TimeDistributed, Conv2D
# Define the model

model = Sequential()

# Add a TimeDistributed Conv2D layer
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'), input_shape=(None, 64, 64, 3)))

# Add a TimeDistributed Flatten layer
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))

# Add an LSTM layer with 128 units
model.add(LSTM(128))

# Add a Dense output layer with 10 units
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
```